# How to get a Clickable Link inside this text string in PHP

Tags: php, text, clickable

I have tried to send an email from PHP with the next body:

```
$message .= 'This is a simple message';
$message .= "\n";
$message .= 'http://www.yahoo.com';
$message .= "\n";
$message .= "<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
$message .= "\n";
```

As a result I got the next output:

```
This is a simple message    //This line is ok
http://www.yahoo.com        //This line is ok
<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a> //It should appear the word Google clickable but it does not
```

Instead of having the word **Google** with the link clickable to the Google site I get the html code, how could I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, haven't tried it but maybe try:

```
$message .= '<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>';
```

NOTE: added double quotes in href link

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you're sending mail as HTML and not as text/plain that is probably in your case so you get HTML as source code and not as it should look like.

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

more read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp):